# Import Java code into Swift iOS app?

Tags: java, ios, swift

How to import Java code into the Swift iOS project, if it is possible to do so?

I tried to look for the solution but did not find any promising solution.

Comment: It can't be done using Apple's tools.  No iOS device runs a JVM, and Apple provides no tools to compile or translate Java to native code.

Comment: thnks @Avi , can we import Java Script code into the Swift IOS

Comment: Javascript is completely different.  It's possible to use JS in an iOS app.  Take a look at JavaScriptCore.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Multi-OS Engine: https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine

with tutorials at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/08/27/tutorials-and-quick-start-guides-for-multi-os-engine

You can create iOS applications on Java (on Mac or Windows) and reuse existing iOS libraries in this app.

[image]